# How to specify a conservative Design of Experiment when runs could be missing?

Tags: experiment-design

I have to design an experiment with 3 input variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and I have 25 available runs which I can use. A full factorial design with center point and 2 replications would be 18 runs, so I sill have 7 runs left.

One important thing is that this experiment is risky, so the chance of any one run not working is not negligible. Normally I would then choose 3 replications, but that would mean 27 runs, 2 more than the ones that I have.

I could also add some middle points (in red in figure below) but I don't know if I win any information and I don't get any safety regarding experiments not working out.

[image]

What would be the best design given these restrictions?

Comment: You could run the first experiment to determine the least significant variable.  Then use the remaining seven experiments (provide no need for repeats) for a validation with the two significant variables.

Comment: Hi Dave2e, thanks for the idea, I have to specify all the 25 runs at order time but I have a good idea about what would be the most significant variables, I could try repeating those. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you add (as an edit to the post) info on which effects you expect to be important? Only main effects? Also two-factor interactions? Maybe for the third replicate, choose a half-fraction (main-effect plan)